# WSO2 Enterprise Store 1.0.0: store design

Tags: responsive-design, wso2, wso2-es

WSO2 ES has an elegant and attractive portal to browse the store. But it lacks the responsive design needed to adapt the layout to the device's size.

I know the code is fully customizable. But I think it needs more documentation about this.

Are you working on new designs for future versions?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment ES only supports up to the tablet level, and smaller device support is already in our road-map and we are working on this.

You can find the ES source here[1], build and try improvements without waiting till the next release. You can report issues/features at[2] or [3].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/enterprise-store
[2] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/STORE
[3] https://github.com/wso2/enterprise-store/issues